# Use of degli vs dei

Tags: grammar

Why have I seen written, Valle degli Dei, valley of the Gods, and not Valle dei Dei?
I thought gli went before s plus consonant or a vowel in the plural?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Your question seems to be addressed in detail in the link above. For this reason, it will be closed as duplicate. Please, let us know if you have any doubts.